# ACF Date Based wp_query

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I've been trying to order these exhibitions based on the end_date custom field created with Advanced Custom Fields. I'm not able to properly get this working. I need the most recent dates first. I need to also only get posts with the `exhibition_status` of `past`. For the life of me I can't get this working and the below code is just the latest non working interation.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'         => 'exhibitions',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
            'query_one'     => array(
                'key'       => 'exhibition_status',
                'value'     => 'past',
            ),
            'query_two'     => array(
                'key'       => 'end_date',
                'compare'   => '>=',
            ), 
    ),
    'orderby'                => 'end_date',
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
);
```

The date is based on this format F j, Y

How do I get all posts ordered by the ACF field `end_date` and only get posts where the ACF field `exhibition_status` equals `past`?

Comment: Ordeby can not be a unknown field. You need to add another parameter `'meta_key' => 'end_date'` and set the `'order_by' => 'meta_value'`.

Comment: Unfortunetly, that has no effect on the end results.

Comment: Also the `'relation' => 'OR'` should be `'relation' => 'AND'`

Comment: Still the same. I don't get it. Its seems to be kind of sorting them but early dates are still showing before more recent dates in some case....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your existing code.Can you please try the code bellow:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
    'meta_query'=> array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'exhibition_status',
            'value'     => 'past',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'end_date',
            'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
            'type'      => 'DATE'
        ), 
    ),
    'meta_key'    => 'end_date',
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
);
```

Comment: Still giving me the same result.

Comment: Well, I think I figured it out. I had the feeling something else was effecting the order besides end_date. I added this before the $args: remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');.

That seemed to give the correct results but it was reverse order so I changed the order to DESC and everthing seems to be in the correct order... Not really sure what the heck is happening but if there is a more proper way to fix this let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sabbir. You deserve the credit for this one.

Comment: You are welcome